Field strength tensor written as commutator of covariant derivatives in QED
I am currently trying to understand the derivation of the relation
$$
\begin{equation}
F_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{iq}[D_{\mu}, D_{\nu}]\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
$$
in QED and I have trouble with one step in the calculation.
I tried to derive this starting from the commutator acting on a fermion field $\psi$ and obtained the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hspace{0cm}[D_{\mu}, D_{\nu}]\psi &= [\partial_{\mu} + iqA_{\mu}, \partial_{\nu} + iqA_{\nu}]\psi\\
&= \left( [\partial_{\mu}, \partial_{\nu}] + iq[\partial_{\mu}, A_{\nu}] + iq[A_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}] - q^2[A_{\mu}, A_{\nu}] \right)\psi\\
&= iq\left( \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu} A_{\mu} + A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} - A_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \right)\psi\\
&= iqF_{\mu\nu}\psi + iq\left( A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} - A_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \right)\psi
\end{aligned}
$$
where I used $[\partial_{\mu}, \partial_{\nu}]\psi = [A_{\mu}, A_{\nu}]\psi=0$.
If I did not make a mistake until now this would mean that for \eqref{eq1} to be true we must have
$$
iq\left( A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} - A_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \right)\psi = 0.\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
But I cannot see why this should be true and everywhere I looked this isn't adressed at all.
So what exactly am I missing here? Is there a mistake in my derivation or is there a simple reason why \eqref{eq2} is true?
Any help is appreciated.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622315/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259126/2451 and links therein.

Just use the product rule of differentiation to evaluate commutators:
$$
[\partial_\mu,f(x)]=\partial_\mu f(x)-f(x)\partial_\mu=(\partial_\mu f(x))+f(x)\partial_\mu-f(x)\partial_\mu=(\partial_\mu f(x)) \ ,
$$
where $(\partial_\mu f(x))$ means that the differentiation acts only on the operator-valued function $f(x)$, and not generally on everything to the right.
Then we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
{}
[D_\mu,D_\nu]
&=
[\partial_\mu+iqA_\mu,\partial_\nu+iqA_\nu] \\
&=
[\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu]+iq[\partial_\mu,A_\nu]+iq[A_\mu,\partial_\nu]-q^2[A_\mu,A_\nu] \\
&=
iq[\partial_\mu,A_\nu]-iq[\partial_\nu,A_\mu] \\
&=
iq\Big((\partial_\mu A_\nu)-(\partial_\nu A_\mu)\Big) \\
&=
iqF_{\mu\nu} \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We used that $[A_\mu,A_\nu]=0$ in abelian gauge theories.

The derivative operators in the second commutator in the second line of Eq. 1 1/2 also act on the wave function via the chain rule. This cancels the third commutator.

Your mistake is after the third line of your equations.
Bear in mind that the operators in $(...)$ act on the $\psi$ on the right,
and then apply the product rule carefully.
$$\begin{align}
&... \\
&=iq(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu+A_\mu\partial_\nu-A_\nu\partial_\mu)\psi\\
&=iq(\partial_\mu(A_\nu\psi)-\partial_\nu(A_\mu\psi)+A_\mu\partial_\nu\psi-A_\nu\partial_\mu\psi)\\
&=iq((\partial_\mu A_\nu)\psi+A_\nu(\partial_\mu\psi)-(\partial_\nu A_\mu)\psi-A_\mu(\partial_\nu\psi)+A_\mu\partial_\nu\psi-A_\nu\partial_\mu\psi)\\
&=iq((\partial_\mu A_\nu)\psi-(\partial_\nu A_\mu)\psi)\\
&=iqF_{\mu\nu}\psi
\end{align}$$
