# Scalar Field Theories

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, field-theory, notation, differentiation

The Lagrangian density for a single real scalar field theory is \begin{equation}\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}-V(\phi)\end{equation} I have often seen this written \begin{equation}\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-V(\phi)\end{equation} which appears to differ in the kinetic term.

Specifically \begin{equation}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}=(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(\partial^{\mu}\phi)\neq\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi=(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(\partial^{\mu}\phi)+\phi\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\end{equation} where the product rule has been used in the last equality. Is this just sloppy notation (which is acceptable because only first derivatives in the field are considered anyway), or is my maths very bad?

Comment: $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$ _always_ means $(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(\partial^{\mu}\phi)$. I have never seen it mean $\partial_\mu ( \phi \partial^\mu \phi )$

Comment: You seem to think the implicit bracketing in $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$ is $\partial_\mu (\phi\partial^\mu \phi)$. Why?

Comment: @ACuriousMind If I had $x(t)$, $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ then given $\frac{d}{dt}xyz$ I would assume it meant $\frac{d}{dt}(xyz)$ and not $(\frac{d}{dt}x)(yz)$, so I've used that logic here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The notations $(\partial\phi)^{2}$ and $(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{2}$ are shorthands  for $(\partial_{\mu}\phi)g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\nu}\phi)$, where $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse metric tensor.
2. Generally speaking, different authors use different notation concerning how far derivatives act to the right. When in doubt, it is a good idea to insert extra parentheses or spaces in the notation. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) related Phys.SE post.
3. However, in the specific context of OP's kinetic term $\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi$, it seems universally accepted that it is supposed to mean $(\partial_{\mu}\phi)\partial^{\mu}\phi$ as opposed to $\partial_{\mu}(\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi)$.