# Question about commutators acting on wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, notation, differentiation, commutator

Consider a commutator acting on a 1D wavefunction:
$$[\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx},x]\psi(x)=(\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx}x-x\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx})\psi(x).$$

Now does this mean

1. $\frac{\hbar}{i} (\frac{d}{dx}x) \psi(x)-x\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx} \psi(x)$ or
2. $\frac{\hbar}{i} (\frac{d}{dx}x \psi(x))-x\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx} \psi(x)?$

In the first cast $\frac{d}{dx}$ only acts on $x$. In the second case $\frac{d}{dx}$ acts on $x\psi (x)$. Which is correct?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Note on formatting : if you need larger brackets try using "\left(" and "\right)" and similar for other bracket types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only sensible interpretation is the second one: any operator like $P$ or $X$ acts on whatever is to its right. For instance in linear algebra, if we have two matrices/operators $A,B$ and a vector $v$, then $ABv$ really means $A(B(v))$ and likewise
$$[A,B]v = ABv - BAv = A(B(v)) - B(A(v)).$$
In your case, you can check this easily. One the one hand we have the famous commutator
$$[-i\hbar \frac{d}{d x}, x] = -i \hbar.$$
Interpretation (1) is not consistent with the above formula; interpretation (2) is.

Comment: Regarding your matrices/vector argument, we can also represent wavefunctions/vectors as a Nx1 matrix, and by the associative property of matrices, $A(Bv)=(AB)v$. So $A$ can only act on $B$ instead of $Bv$. How does one resolve this problem?

Comment: It's a moot point since matrix multiplication is associative; in this case $(AB)(v) = A(B(v))$. In general you shouldn't think of matrix multiplication as an operator "acting on" something. Operators (matrices) can only act on states (vectors).