# Commutation relation of $e^{ikx}$ and $\partial_x$ in Nakahara

Tags: operators, differentiation, notation

I'm reading through Nakahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics and I don't understand the following derivation on pg. 41:

$$
\text{Now we find from the commutation relation of } \partial_x \equiv \frac{d}{dx} \text{ and } e^{ikx} \text{ that}
\\
\partial_x e^{ikx}  = ik e^{ikx} + e^{ikx} \partial_x = e^{ikx} ( ik + \partial_x)
$$

Why do we need the second term? $\partial_x$ seems to be just an ordinary derivative so why is the $e^{ikx} \partial_x $ term necesary ?

Comment: It's just the product rule of derivatives, really.

Comment: Related: [Do derivatives of operators act on the operator itself or are they “added to the tail” of operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is correct. Note that the *commutator* of $\partial_x$ and $e^{ikx}$ can be computed to be

$$ [\partial_x , e^{ikx}] = \partial_x e^{ikx} - e^{ikx} \partial_x = ik e^{ikx} $$

To show this, consider the action of the commutator on a function $F(x)$ i.e,

$$ [\partial_x , e^{ikx}]F(x) = \partial_x e^{ikx} F(x)- e^{ikx}\partial_x F(x)
= e^{ikx}\partial_x F(x) + ik e^{ikx}F(x) - e^{ikx} \partial_x F(x)$$

which means that
$$ [\partial_x , e^{ikx}]F(x) = ik e^{ikx}F(x)$$

Or in other words,

$$ \partial_x e^{ikx} - e^{ikx} \partial_x = ike^{ikx}$$

Therefore
$$\partial_x e^{ikx} = ik e^{ikx} + e^{ikx}\partial_x $$

or

$$\boxed {\partial_x e^{ikx} = e^{ikx} ( ik + \partial_x)}$$

Comment: I believe it is not a typo because the author then goes on to use the expression $\partial_x^n e^{ikx} = e^{ikx}( ik + \partial_x)^n$

Comment: How are they incorrect?

Comment: The second expression should read $$\{\partial_x ,  e^{ikx} \} = e^{ikx} ( ik +2 \partial_x)$$

Answer (score 6):

Whenever computing commutators, we must understand the operators (here $\partial_x$ and $e^{ikx}$) to act on *everything* to the right. So when writing something like $\partial_x e^{ikx}$ it should be understood to mean the *operator*. That is, the operator such that for any function $f(x)$, it acts as $\partial_x (e^{ikx}f(x))$. Hence the second term you mention is precisely the derivative hitting this $f(x)$.

It is an unfortunate notation, but also rather common throughout physics, particularly when dealing with generators, commutators, and so on. If the derivative was intended to act only on the exponential, it would be written $\partial_x(e^{ikx})$.

The idea behind this is as follows. Suppose we have a vector $\boldsymbol v$ and two matrices $M$ and $N$ and wish to compute $MN\boldsymbol v$. We know that this is equivalent to first computing $N\boldsymbol v$ and then applying $M$ to the result. So here when we are multiplying operators, the idea is to take a "vector" (function) $f(x)$ and first apply $e^{ikx}$ to obtain $e^{ikx}f(x)$. Then we apply $\partial_x$ to this, so necessarily the derivative should hit both factors.

Answer (score 2):

The commutation relation for $\partial_x$ and $e^{ikx}$ is $$\partial_x e^{ikx} - e^{ikx} \partial_x = ike^{ikx}$$
Note that $$\partial_x e^{ikx}$$ here is an operator on some not shown function so the product rule for differentiation is used.