# Commutator of exponentiated operators $[e^\hat{A}, \hat{B}]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

In Nakahara's derivation of the path-integral in "Geometry, Topology and Physics" the following identity is used
$$
 \partial_x^n e^{ikx} = e^{ikx}(ik + \partial_x)^n\tag{1}
$$
to obtain
$$
e^{-i\epsilon[-\partial_x^2 / 2m + V(x) ]} e^{ikx} = e^{ikx} e^{-i \epsilon [-(ik+\partial_x)^2/2m + V(x)]}\tag{2}
$$

which seems to suggest you can just directly apply the first formula even though the operator $\partial_x^n$ is exponentiated. I want to understand how we get this second expression, is there some relation between $ [\hat{A}, \hat{B}]$ and $[\hat{A}, e^{\hat{B}}]$ which was used?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591936/2451

Comment: Please try this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591936/commutation-relation-of-eikx-and-partial-x-in-nakahara).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. OP's two formulas are special cases of
   $$e^{A}f(B)e^{-A}~=~f(e^{A}Be^{-A})~=~f(e^{[A,\cdot]}B)~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~f(B+[A,B]).\tag{1}$$
   The last equality in (1) holds if
   $$ [A,[A,B]]~=~0. \tag{2}$$
2. For a general relationship between $[e^{A},B]$ and $[A,B]$, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52012/2451) Phys.SE post.