# Ambiguity in Notation for Operators in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation, notation, commutator

Let's say I am trying to find the commutator of operators $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, and I get
$$[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]=\nabla^2 f(x,y,z).\tag{0}$$

There seems to be some ambiguity here.

In operator notation, which usually does not include the test function $g$, what is the notational standard used to distinguish

$$[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}] g = \nabla^2 (f(x,y,z)g)\tag{1}$$

and

$$[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}] g = (\nabla^2 f(x,y,z))g\tag{2}$$

where $g$ depends on $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: The notation that you used in the first equation means the equation in the middle. If you mean it to be the last equation, then you should just write f'(x), or at least the f next to the top differential, to avoid confusion. But only you know which of the two options is correct, because you derived the original expression.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Do derivatives of operators act on the operator itself or are they "added to the tail" of operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) and links therein.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I am wondering what general conventions distinguish the two. What you proposed only works for a specific case, so I updated the question to inquire about a more troublesome case.

Comment: It is a grammatical problem, not a mathematical one. The notation you used is ambiguous, that is all.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Thank you, that addresses what I was wondering. Can you recommend a less ambiguous standard for notation?

Comment: I am not sure what would be the standard way for an example like the one you used. But I would replace the Laplacian by the momentum operator (divided by $-h^2$).

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Even with that change, how would you indicate, for example, a commutator $[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}] \psi = (\mathbf{p} f(x,y,z))\psi$?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, I would do that only if you mean Eq. (1). In that case you dont need to write $\psi$. Also, I meant the square of the momentum operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If operators $A$ and $B$ have commutation relation
$$[A,B] = g \mathbb I $$
for some function $g:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb C$, then that means $[A,B]\psi = g\psi$, which we might also write
$$\bigg([A,B]\psi\bigg)(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z)  \psi(x,y,z)$$
My interpretation of OP's expression $(0)$ is precisely this, with $g(x,y,z)\equiv \nabla^2 f(x,y,z)$.   However, as OP points out, there is some ambiguity here, so some subsequent clarification on the part of the writer would be warranted. A less ambiguous notation for OP's expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ might be

$$[A,B] = (\nabla^2 f)\mathbb I + 2(\nabla f) \cdot \nabla + f \nabla^2 \tag{1'}$$
$$[A,B] = (\nabla^2 f) \mathbb I \tag{2'}$$

As is often the case, you need to find the proper balance between notational brevity and clarity which suits your audience and style.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It seems there is no widespread standard notation and clarification from the writer is needed. What is $\mathbb I$? I have not seen that before.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan $\mathbb I$ is the identity operator on the Hilbert space, to remind us that both sides of $[A,B]=g\mathbb I$ are to be understood as operators. Because the right hand side corresponds to simple multiplication of a wavefunction by the function $g$ it is common to just drop the symbol $\mathbb I$ and write $[A,B]=g$, but for pedagogical clarity I like to keep it in.

Answer (score -1):

If the former solution was what you intended to mean, then you wouldn't write $d/dx f(x)$ -- to my eyes, I would not think from this expression that the derivative is supposed to act on the test function. Instead, you would keep the product rule in mind and write
$$
\frac{df}{dx} + f(x) \frac{d}{dx} 
$$

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, frankly. But the question is far from clear.

Comment: If the derivative was a 4th derivative, this solution would not be appropriate. I am looking for something more general.

Comment: Why not? You can still apply the product rule derivative by derivative and obtain an unambiguous expression in a similar manner.

Comment: @Gert In what way can I make my question more clear? What notational convention distinguishes equation (1) and (2) in the original question?

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan It would help to use Dirac notation.