# Exponential of an operator shifted by the derivative operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, group-theory, differentiation, commutator

Let $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ be sufficiently smooth functions and $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. It is easy to show that $$e^{p(x)D}f(x)=f(e^{p(x)D}x).\tag{1}$$

If $p(x)=a \in \mathbb{R}$ , we have the shift operator as $e^{aD}f(x)=f(x+a)$.

I appreciate it if you could help me to get answers for the following questions:

First, if $p=D$, can we say that $$e^{DD}f(x)=f(x+D)~?\tag{2}$$

**Update:** The first question is answered below. No, LHS is a function and RHS is an operator.

Second, what is the relationship between $e^{p(x+D)D}f(x)$ and $e^{p(x)D}f(x)$? For instance:

$$e^{p(x+D)D}f(x)-e^{p(x)D}f(x)=(e^{p(x+D)D}-e^{p(x)D})f(x)= \qquad ?\tag{3}$$

$$\frac{e^{p(x+D)D}}{e^{p(x)D}}=e^{p(x+D)D} e^{-p(x)D}=\qquad ?\tag{4}$$

or is it possible to somehow simplify $e^{p(x+D)D}f(x)$?

---

**Update:** The problem above seems to be ambiguious. I decided to rephrase it as follows:

Assume that $p(x)$ ($p:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) in known numerically, is it possible to find a matrix representation of operator $p(x+D)D$? or is it possible to define $p(x+D)D$ at all?

Comment: I would think that $e^{DD} f(x)$ would work out to be function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(2n)}(x)/n!$, not an operator like $f(x + D)$.

Comment: Good point Michael. $e^{DD}f(x)$ is a function but $f(x+D)$ is an operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

People are liable to make mistakes in Heaviside operator calculus manipulations, as they forget symbols on the right. Here is a trick to reduce your $e^{DD}$ to the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform#The_inverse_transform), namely convolution with a Gaussian.

Adapt the identity
$$
e^{u^2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}    \! dy ~ e^{-y^2/4} e^{-uy},
$$
to the formal one,
$$
e^{D^2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! dy ~ e^{-y^2/4} e^{-yD},
$$
so, then, effectively, a linear combination of your starting Lagrange translation operator.

You then have
$$
e^{D^2} f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\! \! dy ~ e^{-y^2/4} e^{-yD} f(x)\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\! \! dy ~ e^{-y^2/4}  f(x-y).
$$

So your (2) is not *even* wrong.

You may learn more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2108889/362193) and links therein...

---

*(Soft) Addendum on comments*  
<sub>When $[p,D]\neq 0$, you are not in Kansas anymore, and Lagrange's rewriting of the Taylor expansion fails dramatically and insidiously. Indeed, occasionally you see c-number arguments of functions shifted by operators, as in deformation quantization, but such operators commute with everything relevant and behave like c-numbers in that context. Your case, by contrast, is a recipe for grief.</sub>

<sub>Your proposed $\phi(x,t)=e^{t p(x+D)D} f(x)$, s.t.   $\phi(x,0)= f(x)$ and $\phi(x,1)= e^{p(x+D) D }f(x)$ and
$\partial_t \phi(x,t)= p(x+D)D \phi (x,t)$, is true, and is a standard Hausdorff move in [CBH expansion procedures](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/CBH.pdf), as Lie algebra books cover. But I am not quite sure what you are really up to, so I couldn't comment. Your (4) is ill-defined, as the numerator and denominator don't commute.</sub>

<sub>As you are exploring your way, make sure your  constructions agree with the known case in $e^{txD} f(x) = e^{t{d\over d\ln x}} f(e^{})= f(xe^t) $.</sub>

Comment: Thank you Cosmas. I found this answer helpful.  I am aware of the Weierstrass transform and am mainly concerened with $p(x+D)$ operator. Based on the link above and the links therein, I see that $e^{p(x+D)D}f$ is the solution of $\frac{d}{dt}\phi(x,t)=p(x+D)D\phi(x,t)$, with $\phi(x,0)=f(x)$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I mean the solution at $t=1$. I am wondering whether it would be possible to find a differential equation that $p(x+D)f$ is its solution (?)

Comment: I updated the question @Cosmas. The intention is defining $p(x+D)D$ if $p(x)$ is known.

Comment: If the power series of *p(x)* is known, *p(x+D)* is well defined and messy. You want a "normal-ordered" form with all *D* s to the right? Like $(x+D)^2= x^2+1 +2xD +D^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The data that I have ($p$ and $f$) are numerically known. If I know the action of $p(x+D)D$ I can compute $e^{p(x+D)D}f$.

What if we represent $p$ locally with cubic/quadratic spline? The highest degree is 3 or 2. Will it simplify the calculation?

Comment: You can certainly normal order the cubic, as i did the quadratic....

Comment: If I understood you correctly, if $p(x)$ is NOT represented in a polynomial form and is only known numerically, we cannot define $p(x+D)$ (?)

Comment: I suspect so... Unless you imply chuck the Ds in the end, (.) and so you just read off the shifted x-dependence of your cubic spline...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135536/discussion-between-mirar-and-cosmas-zachos).

Answer (score 3):

1. In OP's equations it is ambiguous how far to the right the operator $D\equiv\frac{d}{dx}$ is acting. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) Phys.SE post for a similar ambiguity.
2. *Example.* OP's eq. (1) is not true in general as an operator identity where $D$ acts all the way to the right. Take e.g. $p(x)=a$ and $f(x)=x^2$ in eq. (1). Then$^1$
   $$LHS ~=~e^{p(x)D}f(x)~=~e^{aD}x^2~=~ (x+a)^2e^{aD}$$
   while
   $$RHS~=~f(e^{p(x)D}x)~=~(e^{aD}x)^2~=~ (x+a)(x+2a)e^{2aD}$$
3. *Example.* OP's eq. (2) is not true in general as an operator identity where $D$ acts all the way to the right. Take e.g. $f(x)=x$ in eq. (2). Then
   $$LHS ~=~e^{D^2}f(x)~=~e^{D^2}x~=~ (x+2D)e^{D^2}$$
   while
   $$RHS ~=~f(x+D)~=~x+D$$
4. Let's introduce a full stop notation "." to indicate how far $D$ acts to the right.
5. *Example.* OP's eq. (1) is not true in general as a function identity if we insert a full stop "." to the right of each side. Take e.g. $p(x)=a$ and $f(x)=x^2$ in eq. (1). Then
   $$LHS ~=~e^{p(x)D}f(x).~=~e^{aD}x^2.~=~ (x+a)^2$$
   while
   $$RHS~=~f(e^{p(x)D}x).~=~(e^{aD}x)^2.~=~ (x+a)(x+2a)$$
6. We can formulate a correct version of OP's eq. (1) as follows:
   $$\begin{align} e^{p(x)D}f(x). 
   ~=~&e^{p(x)D}f(x)e^{-p(x)D}. \cr
   ~=~&e^{p(x)D}f(x)e^{-p(x)D} \cr
   ~=~&f(e^{p(x)D}xe^{-p(x)D}) \cr
   ~=~&f(e^{p(x)D}xe^{-p(x)D}.) \cr
   ~=~&f(e^{p(x)D}x.)
   \end{align} \tag{1}$$
7. *Example.* OP's eq. (2) is not true in general as a function identity if we insert a full stop "." to the right of each side. Take e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ in eq. (2). Then
   $$LHS~=~e^{D^2}f(x). ~=~e^{D^2}x^2.~=~ x^2+D^2x^2.~=~x^2+2$$
   while
   $$RHS ~=~f(x+D).~=~(x+D)^2.~=~ (x+D)x.~=~x^2+1$$
   It doesn't help if we put the full stop in a different place, e.g.
   $$RHS ~=~f(x+D.)~=~(x+D.)^2~=~x^2$$
8. There are similar issues with many of OP's other formulas.

--

$^1$ *Notation.* Note that one often implicitly identify a function, say, $p: x\mapsto p(x)$ with its corresponding left [multiplication operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_operator) $m_p: g(x) \mapsto (m_p g)(x):=p(x)g(x)$, or a value $p(x)$ of the function.

Comment: In my understanding, if a differential operator acts on a real function ($f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$), it produces a function. In your example, 

$$e^{aD}x^{2}=(1+aD+\frac{1}{2}a^{2}D^{2}+...)x^{2}=x^{2}+2ax+a^{2}+ 0 + 0 + ... = (x+a)^{2}$$

Similarly, RHS is equal to $(x+a)^{2}$ because $e^{aD}$ acting on $x$, generates $x+a$. 


I am sorry, but I do follow your line of reasoning in this answer. Are you trying to say that the problem above is not correctly posed?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Qmechanic. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the full stop "." notation. Do you mind pointing me to a reference? 

Additionally, do you believe that the problem, defined as it is, is ambiguous? Do you have any suggestion for improvement?

Comment: Is the full stop notation unclear?

Comment: Yes. And the main question is whether I should modify the question description to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it is not ambigious now.