# Commutator between covariant derivative and a field

Tags: operators, gauge-theory, differentiation, notation, commutator

I have field as an element of a Lie algebra as $\Phi = \phi^at^a$ and I want to calculate the commutator $$[D_{\mu}, \Phi],$$
with $$D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + igA^a_{\mu}t^a,$$ the covariant derivative, where ${t^a}$ are the generators of the group.
When the professor did the calculation explicitly, he did $$[\partial_{\mu}, \Phi] = \partial_{\mu}\Phi - \Phi\partial_{\mu} = (\partial_{\mu}\Phi) + \Phi\partial_{\mu} - \Phi\partial_{\mu}.$$ I don't understand this last step.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Remember what the commutator acts on and then use the product rule.

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to evaluate the commutator on a function, i.e.

$$[\partial_\mu,\Phi]f=\partial_\mu(\Phi f)-\Phi\partial_\mu f=(\partial_\mu \Phi)f+\Phi \partial_\mu f-\Phi \partial_\mu f.$$

The last step is just applying the product rule for differentiation. The RHS can also be written as $(\partial_\mu \Phi+\Phi \partial_\mu-\Phi \partial_\mu)f$, so $[\partial_\mu,\Phi]=\partial_\mu \Phi+\Phi \partial_\mu-\Phi \partial_\mu$.

Comment: Thanks so much!