# Bianchi identity contradiction in Abelian case

Tags: gauge-theory, differentiation, notation, lie-algebra, yang-mills

In non-abelian gauge theory, such as P & S's chapter 15, eq. (15.89), we also have Bianchi identity.

Start with
$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}[D_\nu,[D_\lambda,D_\sigma]]=0$$
and use $[D_\mu,D_\nu]=-ig\vec{F_{\mu \nu}}$, where $\vec{F_{\mu \nu}}=F_{\mu \nu}^at^a$, we obtain
$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(D_\nu \vec{F_{\lambda \sigma}})=0$$

I think this formula is general, which includes abelian case.   However, I find contradiction in Abelian case.

In Abelian case, $[D_\mu,D_\nu]=ieF_{\mu \nu}$, where $F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$, and $D_\nu=\partial_\nu+ieA_\nu$, so we have
$$\begin{aligned}&\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(D_\nu F_{\lambda \sigma}) \\
&=\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(\partial_\nu F_{\lambda \sigma}+ieA_\nu F_{\lambda \sigma} )=0 
\end{aligned}$$
However, we already know that $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}\partial_\nu F_{\lambda \sigma}=0$ from $\partial_\nu F_{\lambda \sigma}+\partial_\lambda F_{\sigma \nu}+\partial_\sigma F_{\nu \lambda}=0$. Which means we must have
$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}A_\nu F_{\lambda \sigma}=2\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}A_\nu\partial_\lambda A_\sigma=0 $$

But this seems not equal to zero.

Comment: Which reference puts an arrow over $F_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: @Qmechanic Since according to P & S's book eq.(15.32), $[D_\mu,D_\nu]=-igF_{\mu \nu}^a t^a$. So I thought there should be an arrow to contain the Lie algebra. Would my thought right? There are also Lie algebras inside $D_\mu$.

Comment: Aha, an arrow to indicate a vector. An arrow is a bit unusual notation in this context.

Comment: Thank you, so I think the correct bianchi identity for non-abelian should be $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda \sigma}[D_\nu,F_{\lambda \sigma}^a t^a]=0$, right?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's question seems spurred by an ambiguity in the notation for differential operators, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451) related Phys.SE post.

There is a Lie-bracket/commutator in the 2nd Bianchi identity:
$$ \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}[D_{\nu},F_{\lambda\sigma}]=0. $$

In the abelian case the Lie-bracket is zero, so we can replace the covariant derivative with a partial derivative:
$$ \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}[\partial_{\nu},F_{\lambda\sigma}]=0. \qquad\text{(Abelian case)}$$