# Evaluating the commutator of derivative and position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation, notation, commutator

In Zettili's book on quantum, the fully worked problem 2.6 asks to show
$$
\hat{A} = i(\hat{X}^2+1)\frac{d}{dx} + i\hat{X}.
$$
Is Hermitian. Where $\hat{X}$ is the position operator. I took the hermitian conjugate of $\hat{A}$ and end up with the result
$$
\hat{A}^{\dagger} = i\hat{X}^2\frac{d}{dx}+i\left[\frac{d}{dx},\hat{X}^2\right]+i\frac{d}{dx}-i\hat{x}
$$
but when I go to compute the commutator, I have to calculate
$$
\left[\frac{d}{dx},\hat{X}\right]
$$
using $[A,B] = AB-BA$ I get
$$
\left[\frac{d}{dx},\hat{X}\right]=\frac{d}{dx}(x)-x\frac{d}{dx}
=1-x\frac{d}{dx}.
$$
Though in the solution provided in the textbook, they use $\left[\frac{d}{dx},\hat{X}\right]=1$. I'm hoping I'm making a stupid error somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first part of your question, about $A$, isn’t relevant. You’re asking what mistake you’ve made when computing $[d/dx, x]$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55773/2451 and links therein.